# Arithmetic Order in C# vs Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, math, arithmetic-expressions, operator-precedence

The following problem returns different results between C# and Javascript:

JS Result = 0.6987590698013918

C# Result = 0.697932453616849

Javascript

```
mu =0.6962788561718957;
e1= 0.0016792203861749964;
phi1 = mu + e1 * (3 / 2 - 27 * e1 * e1 / 32) * Math.sin(2 * mu) + e1 * e1 * (21 / 16 - 55 * e1 * e1 / 32) * Math.sin(4 * mu);
```

C#

```
double mu = 0.6962788561718957;
double e1 = 0.0016792203861749964;
double phi1 = mu + e1 * (3 / 2 - 27 * e1 * e1 / 32) * Math.Sin(2 * mu) + e1 * e1 * (21 / 16 - 55 * e1 * e1 / 32) * Math.Sin(4 * mu);
```

Javascript and C# share the same double standard so I don't believe the result is different due to precision, especially considering the change starts at the 1000th place. Is there an arithmetic order I am missing that's different between the two languages?

Comment: First thing I'd do is split up the expression and look for the smallest that shows different results. I have my suspicions about the trig functions.

Comment: `3 / 2` results in `1` because it's integer division.

Comment: @DanielA.White I am an idiot. I totally forgot about that behavior in C# Thanks that's it!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have calculations which result in integers, truncating the decimal places.

This is true in C#, but not JavaScript:

```
3 / 2 == 1
```

Answer (score 5):

To achieve same result as in JS, make your divisions with at least one float number.

```
double phi1 = mu + e1 * (3.0 / 2 - 27 * e1 * e1 / 32) * Math.Sin(2 * mu) + e1 * e1 * (21.0 / 16 - 55 * e1 * e1 / 32) * Math.Sin(4 * mu);
```

**3.0 / 2** and **21.0 / 16**

Result: 0.698759069801392